# Connecting MySQL Db from Visual Studio Code, Dot Net

Tags: php, mysql, .net, database, xampp

I'm tired of trying to connect `MySQL` database from visual studio code using `dot net core`.

When I run `MySQL Workbench`, it shows the bug report dialog box(attached image) after sign in with username and password.

I've been using `php` for a long time and I used `Xampp server`.

As you know, `xampp` needs to connect `mysql`. But now, I want to use MySQL Server from visual studio code with dot net core. Is that a problem of conflict with these two?
[image: bug report dialog box image appear]

Comment: U need to check all pluggins (if any) loaded in workbench. If possible, remove and reinstall. Last resort will be try reinstalling whole workbench itself

Comment: I did remove and reinstall, but how to check these plugin.

Comment: it's unclear how MySQL Workbench, which is just a GUI to connect to a MySQL Server, is in any way related to writing some PHP or .NET code to be used as non-GUI clients to connect to a MySQL server. The two should have nothing to do with each other. Have you written some .NET code to do the connection in your .NET program? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Unless you are talking about getting some MySQL GUI visible inside the Visual Studio Code IDE? It's not clear what your meaning is, really. Please clarify. Don't conflate the functionality of the IDE with the programs you write _using_ the IDE.

Comment: I'm sorry ADyson. When we choose dotnet core, it's prequisitics needs to run 1. MySql installer community 2. MySql workbench community 3. dotnet-sdk-latest version. There's no problem with installing all of program but, when i launch MySql Workbench 6.3 C.E, it's show the bug report dialog box after filling username and password.

Comment: Moreover, I used php with phpstorm IDE connecting with xampp, and xampp use MySql and  Apache. Now I write C#, dotnet core with visual studio code IDE and I wanna use MySql again. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think someone give me advice to change Default connection in appsettings.json of VS code. I found some port number, server and password in it. But I have no idea how to change. :'(

Comment: Install mysql connector for windows. Use this library in visual studio as reference lib . You can also set connection string in app setting.

Answer (score 0):

yes i had this problem

and change mysql port to 3307 because mysql xampp hosted on 3306.

and this worked for me.

second is mysql version

i think if you want to connect dotnetcore to mysql you need to use docker or install mysql8 not mysql5 or 5.5